# How to correctly calculate indexes for nested lists using Google Docs API requests?

Tags: google-docs-api

This is my current request object that gives me this error:
"Invalid requests[23].updateParagraphStyle: Index 66 must be less than the end index of the referenced segment, 64.",

A \t or \n get 1 index any other character gets 1. Somehow, I seem to be off by 3 and I can't figure out why. GPT 4 is also really bad at this kind of thing and can't seem to do basic math.

I'm guessing I am misunderstanding indexes in some fashion, but I don't know where I'm going wrong. I can get this to work mostly correctly if I remove the paragraph styling portion. It feels like my indexes are off by a couple though so I am getting weird issues with paragraphs still being part of the list in the ordered list case for example. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here is my original text content:

```
 * Bullet1
   * Bullet2
     * Bullet3
     * Bullet3b

Para1
 1. Ordered1
   1.1 Ordered2
      1.1.1 Ordered3

Para2
```

I'm converting TipTap JSON to a google doc and working on supporting nested lists, my functions generate the follow request array.

```
[
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 1
            },
            "text": "Bullet1"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 8
            },
            "text": "\n"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 9
            },
            "text": "\t"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 10
            },
            "text": "Bullet2"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 17
            },
            "text": "\n"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 18
            },
            "text": "\t"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 19
            },
            "text": "Bullet3"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 26
            },
            "text": "\n"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 27
            },
            "text": "Para1"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 32
            },
            "text": "\n"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 33
            },
            "text": "Ordered1"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 41
            },
            "text": "\n"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 42
            },
            "text": "\t"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 43
            },
            "text": "Ordered2"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 51
            },
            "text": "\n"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 52
            },
            "text": "\t"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 53
            },
            "text": "Ordered3"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 61
            },
            "text": "\n"
        }
    },
    {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "index": 62
            },
            "text": "Para2"
        }
    },
    {
        "createParagraphBullets": {
            "range": {
                "startIndex": 1,
                "endIndex": 27
            },
            "bulletPreset": "BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE"
        }
    },
    {
        "updateParagraphStyle": {
            "range": {
                "startIndex": 27,
                "endIndex": 32
            },
            "paragraphStyle": {
                "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
                "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
                "alignment": "START",
                "lineSpacing": 115,
                "spaceAbove": {
                    "magnitude": 4,
                    "unit": "PT"
                },
                "spaceBelow": {
                    "magnitude": 4,
                    "unit": "PT"
                },
                "indentFirstLine": {
                    "magnitude": 0,
                    "unit": "PT"
                }
            },
            "fields": "alignment,lineSpacing,spaceAbove,spaceBelow,indentFirstLine,namedStyleType"
        }
    },
    {
        "createParagraphBullets": {
            "range": {
                "startIndex": 33,
                "endIndex": 62
            },
            "bulletPreset": "NUMBERED_DECIMAL_NESTED"
        }
    },
    {
        "updateParagraphStyle": {
            "range": {
                "startIndex": 62,
                "endIndex": 67
            },
            "paragraphStyle": {
                "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
                "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
                "alignment": "START",
                "lineSpacing": 115,
                "spaceAbove": {
                    "magnitude": 4,
                    "unit": "PT"
                },
                "spaceBelow": {
                    "magnitude": 4,
                    "unit": "PT"
                },
                "indentFirstLine": {
                    "magnitude": 0,
                    "unit": "PT"
                }
            },
            "fields": "alignment,lineSpacing,spaceAbove,spaceBelow,indentFirstLine,namedStyleType"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: From your showing request body, your input situation is an empty document? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I don't understand how you would get the startIndex and endIndex values for the updateParagraphStyle and createParagraphBullets requests. For example, the ordered list has "Ordered3" starting at index 66, which seems like it would then end at 74, but your createParagraphBullets endIndex is 70. Same for the last updateParagraphStyle, which starts at 67, but the index of the last paragraph is 75. How are you getting the start and end index values that don't match the content?

I updated my answer for using each index of the inputted texts. So, please confirm the following request body and explanation.

#### Modified request body:

```json
[
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 1
      },
      "text": "Bullet1"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 8
      },
      "text": "\n"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 9
      },
      "text": "\t"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 10
      },
      "text": "Bullet2"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 17
      },
      "text": "\n"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 18
      },
      "text": "\t\t"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 20
      },
      "text": "Bullet3"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 27
      },
      "text": "\n"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 28
      },
      "text": "\t\tBullet3b\n"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 39
      },
      "text": "Para1"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 44
      },
      "text": "\n"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 45
      },
      "text": "Ordered1"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 53
      },
      "text": "\n"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 54
      },
      "text": "\t"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 55
      },
      "text": "Ordered2"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 63
      },
      "text": "\n"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 64
      },
      "text": "\t\t"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 66
      },
      "text": "Ordered3"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 74
      },
      "text": "\n"
    }
  },
  {
    "insertText": {
      "location": {
        "index": 75
      },
      "text": "Para2"
    }
  },
  {
    "updateParagraphStyle": {
      "range": {
        "startIndex": 75,
        "endIndex": 81
      },
      "paragraphStyle": {
        "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
        "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
        "alignment": "START",
        "lineSpacing": 115,
        "spaceAbove": {
          "magnitude": 4,
          "unit": "PT"
        },
        "spaceBelow": {
          "magnitude": 4,
          "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentFirstLine": {
          "magnitude": 0,
          "unit": "PT"
        }
      },
      "fields": "alignment,lineSpacing,spaceAbove,spaceBelow,indentFirstLine,namedStyleType"
    }
  },
  {
    "createParagraphBullets": {
      "range": {
        "startIndex": 45,
        "endIndex": 75
      },
      "bulletPreset": "NUMBERED_DECIMAL_NESTED"
    }
  },
  {
    "updateParagraphStyle": {
      "range": {
        "startIndex": 39,
        "endIndex": 45
      },
      "paragraphStyle": {
        "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
        "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
        "alignment": "START",
        "lineSpacing": 115,
        "spaceAbove": {
          "magnitude": 4,
          "unit": "PT"
        },
        "spaceBelow": {
          "magnitude": 4,
          "unit": "PT"
        },
        "indentFirstLine": {
          "magnitude": 0,
          "unit": "PT"
        }
      },
      "fields": "alignment,lineSpacing,spaceAbove,spaceBelow,indentFirstLine,namedStyleType"
    }
  },
  {
    "createParagraphBullets": {
      "range": {
        "startIndex": 1,
        "endIndex": 39
      },
      "bulletPreset": "BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE"
    }
  },
]
```

In my case, the flow for retrieving each index is as follows.

1. Only `insertText` requests are done.
2. Retrieve the values of `startIndex` and `endIndex` by [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get). By this, you can see the following result.

   The start and end index of `Bullet1` and `Bullet3b` are 1 and 39, respectively.
   The start and end index of `Para1` are 39 and 45, respectively.
   The start and end index of `Ordered1` to `Ordered3` are 45 and 75, respectively.
   The start and end index of `Para2` are 75 and 81, respectively.
3. The requests of `updateParagraphStyle` for `Para2`, `createParagraphBullets` for `Ordered1` to `Ordered3`, `updateParagraphStyle` for `Para1`, and `createParagraphBullets` for `Bullet1` to `Bullet3b` are run.

   - In this case, the reversed order of requests is used. Please be careful about this.

#### Testing:

When this request body is used for a new Google Document, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- When `createParagraphBullets` and `updateParagraphStyle` are used, it seems that the index of text is changed. When the initial order is used, it is required to check each index for each request. I thought that this flow might have a high process cost. So, as another approach, I proposed the above flow.

#### Reference:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

Comment: I don't understand how you would get the startIndex and endIndex values for the updateParagraphStyle and createParagraphBullets requests. For example, the ordered list has "Ordered3" starting at index 66, which seems like it would then end at 74, but your createParagraphBullets endIndex is 70. Same for the last updateParagraphStyle, which starts at 67, but the index of the last paragraph is 75. How are you getting the start and end index values that don't match the content?

Comment: @Jed Grant Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When `createParagraphBullets` and `updateParagraphStyle` are used, it seems that the index of text is changed. When the initial order is used, it is required to check each index. I thought that this flow might have a high process cost. So, as another approach, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was looking for but your comment about reversing the order led me to try it and it worked. I had to have the paragraph styles request before the bullet request and they both needed to be in reverse order. I don't really understand why. Test style requests also needed to come before the bullet requests.